# Passing an object between winforms in c++

Tags: c++, winforms, parameter-passing

I'm been trying for sometime to pass an object of a singleton class named `Facade` from `Form1` to `Form2`. Yes, it's a widely discussed topic,but all the sites had worked this problem in c#, and I've tried to adapt those techniques in c++ and it doesn't work, though they work in c#.
In `Form1`

```
    ...
    textBox1->Text=f.getVars1().ToString();
    Form2^ f2=gcnew Form2(f);//error 5
    ...
```

And in `Form2`

```
    Facade f1;
    Form2(Facade f2)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        f1=f2;//error 3

    }
```

And in the `Form2` button event `textBox1->Text=f1.getVars1().ToString();`
It shows these errors when I try it

```
    Error   3   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a 
    right-hand operand of type 'Facade' (or there is no acceptable 
    conversion) 
    Error   5   error C2664: 'FacadeCheck::Form2::Form2(Facade)' : cannot 
    convert parameter 1 from 'Facade' to 'Facade'
```

Also I've almost tried every solution, so anyone please try to solve this in `c++`, it would be a great help. I use 2010 version of ms visual studio...Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `Facade` isn't copyable obviously.

Comment: @user0042 then, what do you suggest me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass and store the object as gc references. In Form2 do:

```
Facade ^ f1;
Form2(Facade ^ f2)
{
  ...
  f1 = f2;
}
```

Comment: yes,I tried it..but it gives errors too. Since I'm passing `Facade` as a reference, I declared it as a reference in `Form1` as `Facade^ f;` when declaring it. Then, in button event method `textBox1->Text=f->getVars1().ToString();` and `Form2^ f2=gcnew Form2(f);`. Then in `Form2`, I did those changes you mentioned and in the button event method of `form2`,`textBox1->Text=f1->getVars1().ToString();.`.

Comment: But  its got errors like `error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000012) Facade::op_Assign `. what should I do now?